# jquery checkbox how many above

Tags: jquery, checkbox, traversal

When checking checkbox_01 div1 toggles.

HTML

```
<div>
    <ul>
       <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_01" /></li>    
        <div id="div1" class="toggle">
            <ul>
                <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_02" /></li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_03" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

expected output

```
checkbox01
-checkbox02
-checkbox03
```

how do I get a level based on the checkboxs?

> var x =  $(this).prevAll('div:has(:checkbox)').find(':checkbox');

Comment: A <div> inside of a <ul> is not valid HTML, perhaps this is breaking it. It needs to be inside an <li>

Comment: What does *div1 toggles* mean? The checkboxes inside toggle their state?

Comment: Your HTML code is in my eyes wrong. If you want the div layer as a part of a list you have to sourround it with <li> tag. You can check that with DOM inspector from FireFox.

Comment: Consider using jsbin, I've got you started here... http://jsbin.com/ulaket

Comment: i want to know how many checkboxes checkbox_03 has previous not including siblings. so i can make a level based on the structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rework your HTML.  It is invalid:

```
<div>
    <ul>
       <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_01" />    
            <div id="div1" class="toggle">
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_02" /></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_03" /></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Notice your `div.toggle` is now inside your `li`.  Then, simply toggle it like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/TqV9g/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you need:

```
$('#div1').hide();
$('#checkbox_01').click(function(){
    $('#div1').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

When you click the checkbox the div "toggles".

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/2XWaU/1/